# Different Styles Within Vector Layer

Tags: javascript, vector, openlayers, styling

Is there any way to configure OpenLayers styling method? I have a vector layer and I would like to style the features depending on a value of a flag variables, so I can't use rules. Lets say I have two types of features: houses and restaurants. houses flag is "H" and restaurants flag is "R". How can I give them a different style within a vector layer?

Answer (score 1):

See lookup and addUniqueValueRules:
http://docs.openlayers.org/library/feature_styling.html